# Facebook share dialogue: picture and title missing

Tags: facebook, dialog, share

I'm having some problems with Facebook share dialogue. No matter how I try, I can't get a picture and title to show up. A link and sharing itself works though.

Here is an example:
https://fri.lv/en/ads/7/4525/4528/?ad=6
(Share button is second from right)

Essentially the same share dialogue works as expected on other site that I created:

http://adverto.lv/en/ads/2/3299/3323/3615/?ad=38
(Share button is second from right)

Can you help me figure this out please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the changelog for v2.9, additional parameters are deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9

You need to use OG tags in the shared URLs instead. I assume the second URL includes the neccessary OG tags already.

Comment: I created both sites, and I can assure, that no OG tags are used on both.

Comment: ok, but you have to use them on both now. you are using different app ids, so i assume one app is just not updated - or the url that works has been shared already and the og tags are not refreshed yet. either way, og tags are neccessary now and you can remove the additional parameters.

Comment: OK, thanx! +1 for you mate